# Why a const variable cannot be passed by reference?

Tags: c++, constants, pass-by-reference

My lecture notes said

> The argument to a reference parameter must be a variable, not a
>   constant or an expression.

And thus

```
int f(double & var); // function prototype
...
const double t = 4.0;
int ret = f(t);
```

`f(t)` is illegal.

But I do not understand, why would `t` be illegal. `t` is a constant, but still a variable, and I don't think there's anything wrong passing `t` by reference.

Comment: You can pass it as `const` reference like this: `int f(const double & var);`

Comment: `t` is not a constant, but a `const` variable. A constant would be 4.0. Your lecture notes are basically saying that you cannot do something like `int ret = f(4.0);`

Comment: @flowit I thought it that way at first, but that example is given in a quiz solution said passing `t` is illegal: `parameter t is defined as a constant, i.e. const, while the formal parameter is pass by reference`

Comment: It *is* possible to pass a constant value (say `4.0`) or `const` variables as reference parameters only as const references. So unless I misunderstood your question, your lecture is incorrect (and I would be worried if it was incorrect for something this elementary) or you missed a detail about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if the function `f` modifies `var`? That shouldn't happen if `t` is `const`.

Here's an example implementation of `f`:

```
int f(double & var)
{
    var += 1;
    return var;
}
```

This will change whatever is passed as an argument. **But** if the argument was `const`... tough luck. Then it's not allowed and the compiler explicitly tells you this.

This is the error generated by the compiler:

```
error: binding reference of type 'double&' to 'const double' discards qualifiers
```

So by passing a `const` variable into the function (without a non-const argument), you're telling the compiler to neglecting the `const`ness of the variable in the first place.

If you wish to pass it by reference, pass it by **`const`**-reference:

```
int f(const double & var)  //  or int f(double const& var)
{
    var += 1;
    return var;
}
```

This tells the compiler to retain the const-ness of its arguments.

Comment: If that const `t` is passed by reference, would that still compile? I thought that would be a runtime error or compile warning

Comment: The function parameter `double & var` states that the parameter should be passed by reference. I'm not understanding what you're trying to say in your comment?

Comment: Never mind, your update illustrates that problem quite clear, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Let me enhance my comment to an answer:

First, `t` is not a constant, but a const variable. A constant would be 4.0. Your lecture notes are basically saying that you cannot do something like int ret = f(4.0);

Second, what you are seeing is a type mismatch. `const` as a qualifier is part of the type. You cannot do the following:

```
const int x = 1;
int& ref_x = x;
```

> error: binding reference of type ‘int&’ to ‘const int’ discards
>   qualifiers

Nevertheless, it is legal to pass `const` qualified variables as reference, either use a const reference or cast away the const:

- Use a const reference `const int& const_int_ref = x;`
- Use const_cast:  `int& rx = const_cast<int&>(x);`

I prefer the first one whereever possible.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a reference parameter the object passed needs to actually (at least be able to) occupy memory, a constant (as opposed to a const variable) does not.

I.E. the following would be okay:

```
void foo(int & n) {
  n = 3;
}
void bar() {
  int i;
  foo(i);
  std::cout << "i is " << i << std::endl;
}
```

but if you had:

```
void qux() {
  foo(3);
}
```

there would be no object for the assignment in foo to assign to.

Note that you can pass a constant as a reference-to-const (i.e. MyType const &), that's allowed because the assignment issue does not exist when the reference is to a const.

Comment: So `const` variables actually have different memory storage method compare to non-const variables? And that's what makes passing by reference illegal for a const variable?